# For a python price finding (webscraper) project, is it possible to take input from user and find that exact product

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am currently attempting to create a python project that asks the user for a product and then displays the lowest price for that product after scraping prices from different websites (e.g. amazon and ebay). However, where I am struggling is that, is it possible to take the user input (name of the product) and then use that input to find that product by webscraping. **Would be highly appreciated if anyone could help as I am quite keen to try and succeed in making this idea of mine. Thanks**

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

For amazon, you can try this kind of url : https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/your_asin

You can take the asin as input to browse a product.
However, Amazon is pretty hard to scrape at scale as they have bot mitigation services (captchas, ip blocking etc)
I'm less aware of ebay but I guess it's pretty much the same idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help I will look into it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline I would recommend is:

1. Learning what URLs for the different providers are called to find the prices of the product.
2. Then creating a module for those URLs fetching the price and details. This is where the actual magic happens. Try to make it flexible so that it can be used by the python script (CLI params as an input) or the WebAPI view (Request params as an input).
3. You can then create your own web service using Flask/Django which asks the user input and fetch the results as you want. This is more user-friendly.
4. Or use that module in the Python script. This is developer-friendly.
5. Later, you can use the endpoint on any frontend.

Hope this answers your doubt.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea. I will be trying this now to see if it works. This adds a lot more clarity now.

Comment: By the way I just wanted to clarify that what do you mean by step 1. Do you mean like a general url for the providers?

Comment: @UzairS In step 1, from the general URL, I meant identifying the URLs of your data source. The URL which you'll be scraping for the data.